# How can I search and sort history in IE, or really any browser

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, history

I find this so frustrating.  I read many technical articles in a day, none really that significant.  Then a day or two later I realize something in that article is now relevant.

I use the search history feature in IE. For instance I know the article was about SQL Indexes, but that piece of garbage doesn't allow to search and sort by date. Considering I might view thousands of articles about SQL Indexes a year...You can see why searching by keyword isn't helpful if I can't sort by date.  What I really want is a way to view pages by order visited and search.

Comment: Firefox lets you search by keywords and date.

Also, quick googling tells me that IE history can be searched using Windows Search. Maybe try that.

Comment: Searching the word 'SQL indexes' in windows search on a machine for sql database development returns A LOT of results. Plus I don't want to turn on Windows Indexing. It slows down the machine.

Comment: There are extensions for Chrome and Firefox that allow for something like this. Your options with IE are limited.  It only slows down the machine while its indexing once it finishes there are no performance costs.

Comment: Can you specify which IE version you are using?

Comment: I have found this http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iehv.html 
Not sure if it works for your version but you might want to try.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind Google watching over what you're reading, [you can have Google Web History track all the sites you visit](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-let-google-watch-over-your-web.html) and then search for these URLs from any computer without burdening your own browser or computer resources.

You can also consider using the [Google Bookmarks bookmarklet](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/) to store favorite URLs easily with your own notes.